# download youtube video in mp3 format in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube, mp3

Is there any way to get .mp3 links for youtube video's? I tried multiple online youtube to mp3 converter sites but it all just downloads the file in system and doesn't give any mp3 link.

Or

Is there any way i can download files from a link, so lets say there is some link like www.somesongdownloader.com, on load of this link in browser mp3 file is getting downloaded. but if i try to download the same from my ios code its just downloading the php file not mp3 file. below is my code -

Below code works fine for mp3 links which i am not able to get for youtube videos but this code is not working for any url which gives mp3 file to download on browser -

```
class func loadFileAsync(url: NSURL, completion:(path:String, error:NSError!) -> Void) {
    print("Inside loadFileAsync")
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
    let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent!)
    if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(destinationUrl.path!) {
        print("file already exists [\(destinationUrl.path!)]")
        completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:nil)
    } else {
        let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    print("response=\(response)")
                    if response.statusCode == 200 {
                        if data!.writeToURL(destinationUrl, atomically: true) {
                            print("file saved [\(destinationUrl.path!)]")
                            completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
                        } else {
                            print("error saving file")
                            let error = NSError(domain:"Error saving file", code:1001, userInfo:nil)
                            completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
                completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get the direct download URL of converted mp3. For that you have to play with the HTML in the webpage of URL used(to convert video into mp3). Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/587931/YouTube-to-mp .. This is not in iOS but you may have to work in similar manner.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the direct download link of converted mp3?

Comment: Not sure, check this once http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/api/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comments, using http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/api/ you can do this.

```
    let videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE"
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=\(videoURL)")
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("response=\(response)")
                if response.statusCode == 200 {
                    if data != nil {
                        do {
                            let responseJSON =  try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary;
                            let urlString = responseJSON["link"] as! String
                            let directDownloadURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

                            // Call your method loadFileAsync
                            YourClass.loadFileAsync(directDownloadURL!, completion: { (path, error) -> Void in
                                print(path)
                            })

                        }
                        catch let JSONError as NSError {
                            print("\(JSONError)")
                        }
                        catch {
                            print("unknown error in JSON Parsing");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
```

I have not done error handling, so you need to further refine this code. But this will surely work. I have tested it.

Comment: I already tried this and No,it did not work :(, its downloading a get file not mp3 file. Also the url what we get from http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/api/ is not a mp3 file.

Comment: Save your file with extension as .mp3. It will work. You can test it by renaming the file named get with extension as .mp3.

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. i got busy with someother work. And no saving file with .mp3 extension dinn work for me. The saved file is not playing. If you have also tried.. did it work for you i mean you were able to play it?

Comment: Yes, I just renamed "get" named file as "get.mp3". And played that file in iTunes. It worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for late response, and your solution works but only few times. Sometime its failing because the youtubeinmp3 link is not returning json format data. I have tested it multiple times, link returns json response sometime and sometime it redirects to different page.

Comment: If youtubeinmp3 link is not working then may be you can check their website for support. Also, this is just an example. If your company is managing own server then a service can be managed on server which can convert youtube video to mp3. Then you can use this web-service. I am not sure about the script for this on server side but you can discuss it with your team.

Comment: it just says **Unsuported URL**

Comment: not working getting error
 finished with error - code: -1001
 HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])