# How to run through a get file redirect in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using swift to access the youtubeinmp3 api and I am stuck. I am quite new to this so please be gentle. Using the api I get a json response and use the link property that gets returned to download a file. However the link I get looks like this : http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=PL6sPTHlt1KHYj6hUsDxW8zjAgcNiU1SXVHIzxnSALX8%2FKNV35SZqd9l5qxk7LOiD%2FcrlIUe5JJvgZxKg0WeMw%3D%3D

The link works fine in a browser like Chrome but the swift app downloads an unknown file, definitely not an mp3.

I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216971/download-youtube-video-in-mp3-format-in-ios-swift) to find the code.

Any ideas on how I could go through the redirect to get to the mp3 download link?
Thank you in advance.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let videoURL1 = (videosArray[indexPath.row]).objectForKey("videoID") as! String
    //let videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(videoURL1)"
    let videoURL = "//www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(videoURL1)"
    let urlString = "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=\(videoURL)"
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=\(videoURL)")
    let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                print("response=\(response)")
                if response.statusCode == 200 {
                    if data != nil {
                        do {
                            let responseJSON =  try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary;
                            //let urlString = NSURL(string:"\(responseJSON["link"] as! String)")
                            //print("URLString: \(urlString)")
                            //let directDownloadURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
                            // Call your method loadFileAsync

                                // code here
                            let urlString = responseJSON["link"] as! String

                            //let finalURLString = urlString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("get", withString: "mp3")

                           print(urlString)

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                                let identifier = NSUUID().UUIDString
                                let downloadItem = DownloadsTableViewCellItem(identifier: identifier, urlString: urlString, infoLabelTitle: selectedName, stateLabelTitle: "Press Download", progressLabelTitle: "", action: DownloadsTableViewCellAction.Download)
                                DownloadsViewController().addDownloadItem(downloadItem, withIdentifier: identifier)

                                SVProgressHUD.showSuccessWithStatus("Download Added")
                                    print("Download Task Added")

                            })

                        }
                        catch let JSONError as NSError {
                            print("\(JSONError)")
                        }
                        catch {
                            print("unknown error in JSON Parsing");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Failure: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Do you know what the end url should be i.e a pattern like `download.youtube...`? If so you can use a `UIWebView` to load the initial URL and then look for the end url, do the check in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`. When you get it, then download the file.

Comment: You could download Alamofire source code and look at how they do it maybe. Or you could just use Alamofire.

Comment: @sbarow Thank you for your quick reply. Could you maybe give me an example as to how I would go about doing something like that?