# Get a WebPage that is modified after loading in swift?

Tags: php, swift, web, mp3

So I want to download a `.mp3` file from a Youtube video. But YT only provides a `.mp4` file (afaik).
So I have to convert the Video to a `.mp3` File. But I don't want to download the video and convert it on device, since it takes too much data..

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216971/download-youtube-video-in-mp3-format-in-ios-swift) was already mentioned that there is an API for it.. sadly it doesn't work anymore...

What I now found is this: https://youtube7.download/mini.php?id=HY_OIwideLg

But they load the `.mp3` link (that I need) asynchronously. So I can't simply do `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:)` because I will get the 'loading'-page only, with no link...

So the question is: How can I get the final loaded html site that returns from this php script?

Comment: Hi, First send a request to : https://www.easy-youtube-mp3.com/convert.php?v=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D**YourVIDEOID** then refresh https://www.easy-youtube-mp3.com/download.php?v=**YourVIDEOID** , If mp3 exists, Download it.(Regx required.)